# How to create folder the same name as user profile not include sub-folder or data just select name and create folder in another drive using cmd

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, batch-processing

I am trying to create a new folder using cmd by creating a folder having the same name as user profile.
Ex: My user profile `C:\Users\Tech` and I want to create a folder with the same name in `D:\Documents\Tech`.

How could I do this?

Comment: Something like this, seems to be what you need, `If Exist "D:\Documents\" If Not Exist "D:\Documents\%UserName%\" MD "D:\Documents\%UserName%"`. To see all of your Environment Variables with their defined values, just enter `set` in a Command Prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need some environment variables for achieving this, as you can see how it looks on my computer:

```
Prompt> set
...
USERNAME=Gebruiker
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Gebruiker
...
```

Using those environment variables you might find what you're looking for, as in following example:

```
Prompt> echo %USERNAME%
Gebruiker

Prompt> echo %USERPROFILE%
C:\Users\Gebruiker

C:\Temp_Folder>mkdir C:\Temp_Folder\%USERNAME%

C:\Temp_Folder>dir /AD
...
 Directory of C:\Temp_Folder

18/10/2020  17:32    <DIR>          .
18/10/2020  17:32    <DIR>          ..
18/10/2020  17:32    <DIR>          Gebruiker
```